# Java.- radio button de verdadero y falso , y poner valor entero en un textfield

Tags: java

**Como puedo asignar un valor valor especifico para cada radioButton y ponerlo en un textField**

```
private void calculoBrutoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       int sistematizacion=0;
       int innovacion=0;
        if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
           sistematizacion=sistematizacion+1;         
        } 
        if  (jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
            innovacion=innovacion+2;

            } 
       bSistematizacion.setText(sistematizacion);
       bInnovacion.setText(innovacion);
       

    }
```

**este está mal porque los textField solo aceptan String, pero como hago apara que en el textField pueda poner un numero, hay otras preguntas que se suman a estos mismos valores**

Answer (score 0):

***Ya lo encontre, es poniendo "String.valuesOf" en el setText, igual lo pongo aquí por si a alguien le sirve***

```
 private void calculoBrutoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        double sistematizacion=0;
        if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
            sistematizacion= sistematizacion+1;
            bSistematizacion.setText(String.valueOf(sistematizacion));
        } 

       if(jRadioButton3.isSelected()){
            sistematizacion= sistematizacion+1;
            bSistematizacion.setText(String.valueOf(sistematizacion));
        }
```